# PHP 100% cpu usage

Tags: nginx, php

One of my php scripts (setup with php-fpm 7.0 with nginx) needs high cpu usage (legitimately) to complete. I would like it to take more time to complete, but leave the cpu available for other requests. Currently the server is not responsive while that script is running.

I could create some delays with PHP sleep(), but is there a more appropriate method for load balancing?

Comment: The solution is to not use all cpu cores. If you have 8 cores, don't start more than 6 PHP threads/processes, leave one spare CPU for other stuff and one spare CPU for your SSH connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [nice](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unice.htm) command in Linux/UNIX. Basically, what it does is running a command with a modified scheduling priority. PHP `sleep()` might not help if running task is heavy by itself - without repeating.

Comment: How can I setup it with ngjnx?

Comment: That is not related to nginx: you spawn another process with `exec()` or `system()`. Command (executed by these) would be something like `nice -n{level-of-niceness} php /path/to/your-script.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sleep (int $seconds)` to pause script execution.
Also there exists microseconds version: `usleep (int $micro_seconds)`.

Using sleep or usleep will stop your script leaving the CPU available for other processes.

Also there is an utility called `nice`. This util controls process priority for CPU. You can use `nice -n 19 php script.php` to reduce script priority to the lowest value. nice priority is `-20` (max priority) to `+19` (min priority).

I think the best solution for you will be `sleep` or `usleep` because this is very simple solution and will not require any modifications to web server and application server.